# Generate a numpy array from a python function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have what I thought would be a simple task in numpy, but I'm having trouble.

I have a function which takes an index in the array and returns the value that belongs at that index. I would like to, efficiently, write the values into a numpy array.

I have found `numpy.fromfunction`, but it doesn't behave remotely like the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) suggests. It seems to "vectorise" the function, which means that instead of passing the actual indices it passes a numpy array of indices:

```
def vsin(i):
    return float(round(A * math.sin((2 * pi * wf) * i)))

numpy.fromfunction(vsin, (len,), dtype=numpy.int16)
# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

(if we use a debugger to inspect `i`, it is a `numpy.array` instance.)

So, if we try to use numpy's vectorised `sin` function:

```
def vsin(i):
    return (A * numpy.sin((2 * pi * wf) * i)).astype(numpy.int16)

numpy.fromfunction(vsin, (len,), dtype=numpy.int16)
```

We don't get a type error, but if `len > 2**15` we get discontinuities chopping accross our oscillator, because numpy is using `int16_t` to represent the index!

The point here isn't about `sin` in particular: I want to be able to write arbitrary python functions like this (whether a numpy vectorised version exists or not) and be able to run them inside a tight C loop (rather than a roundabout python one), and not have to worry about integer wraparound.

Do I really have to write my own cython extension in order to be able to do this? Doesn't `numpy` have support for running python functions once per item in an array, with access to the index?

It doesn't have to be a creation function: I can use `numpy.empty` (or indeed, reuse an existing array from somewhere else.) So a vectorised transformation function would also do.

Comment: FYI, for now I am just running a python loop, which isn't too slow for the small arrays I'm dealing with initially.

Comment: Why aren't you using something like `vsin(np.arange(1000))` or `vsin(np.linspace(0,4,100)`?   Look at `fromfunction` code.  All it does is `vsin(np.indices({len,))`.  If `indices` does not produce the right `i` values, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue of integer wraparound is unrelated to numpy's vectorized `sin` implementation and even the use of python or C.

If you use a 2-byte signed integer and try to generate an array of integer values ranging from 0 to above 32767, you will get a wrap-around error. The array will look like:

```
[0, 1, 2, ... , 32767, -32768, -32767, ...]
```

The simplest solution, assuming memory is not too tight, is to use more bytes for your integer array generated by `fromfunction` so you don't have a wrap-around problem in the first place (up to a few billion):

```
numpy.fromfunction(vsin, (len,), dtype=numpy.int32)
```

`numpy` is optimized to work fast on arrays by passing the whole array around between vectorized functions. I think in general the `numpy` tools are inconvenient for trying to run scalar functions once per array element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not trying to represent any values bigger than INT16_MAX in my array, but the array will be longer than INT16_MAX. With Cython, I can write a function which uses a C iterator rather than a python one, which speeds up jobs like this. I assumed numpy would have something similar built in, but I was apparently wrong.